# Show that, $(-1)^{\mu(1)}+(-1)^{\mu(2)}+...+(-1)^{\mu(n)}<0$ and proof on conjecture of OEIS A209802

Tags: analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

Following is an experimental math claim.

We denote $\mu(a)$ as Möbius function

Let $$F(a)=\sum_{i=1}^{a}(-1)^{\mu(i)}.$$

> Can it be shown that for every positive integer $a$, $F(a)<0$?

Table

$$\begin{array}{|c |c |}  \hline a & F(a) \\ \hline
1 & -1  \\  \hline
2 & -2  \\  \hline
3 & -3  \\ \hline
4 & -2 \\ \hline
5 & -3 \\ \hline
6 &-4 \\ \hline
7 & -5 \\ \hline
8 &-4 \\ \hline
9 &-3 \\ \hline
\vdots &\vdots  \\ \hline
 \end{array}$$

source code PARI/GP

```
for(a=1,100,printf([a, sum(i=1,a,(-1)^moebius(i))]))
[1, -1][2, -2][3, -3][4, -2][5, -3][6, -4][7, -5][8, -4][9, -3][10, -4][11, -5][12, -4][13, -5][14, -6][15, -7][16, -6][17, -7][18, -6][19, -7][20, -6][21, -7][22, -8][23, -9][24, -8][25, -7][26, -8][27, -7][28, -6][29, -7][30, -8][31, -9][32, -8][33, -9][34, -10][35, -11][36, -10][37, -11][38, -12][39, -13][40, -12][41, -13][42, -14][43, -15][44, -14][45, -13][46, -14][47, -15][48, -14][49, -13][50, -12][51, -13][52, -12][53, -13][54, -12][55, -13][56, -12][57, -13][58, -14][59, -15][60, -14][61, -15][62, -16][63, -15][64, -14][65, -15][66, -16][67, -17][68, -16][69, -17][70, -18][71, -19][72, -18][73, -19][74, -20][75, -19][76, -18][77, -19][78, -20][79, -21][80, -20][81, -19][82, -20][83, -21][84, -20][85, -21][86, -22][87, -23][88, -22][89, -23][90, -22][91, -23][92, -22][93, -23][94, -24][95, -25][96, -24][97, -25][98, -24][99, -23][100, -22]
```

The claim holds $\le 10^4$ verified.

I searched but not found this sequence on OEIS. This one is closer [A209802](https://oeis.org/A209802) (not same).

Your suggestions, comments, the answer are valuable to me. Apologies if the claim is just unsolvable. Thank you.

---

Edit, **consequence**: Partial sums of exponential Möbius function is always greater than $0$.

Let $n=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}...p_k^{r_k}$ where $r_i>0,(k\ge i\ge 1)$

$$g(n)=\prod_{1\le i\le k}\mu(r_i)$$

$$G(a)=\sum_{n=1}^ag(n)$$

$g(n)$ know as exponential Möbius function. sequence, [link](https://oeis.org/A166234).

Sequence $G(a)$ [link*,(A209802)](https://oeis.org/A209802) knows as Partial sums of exponential Möbius function. It is conjecture that $G(a)>0$ in the comment section of the link*. And here is the proof.

Note

$$  g(n) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{then $(-1)^{\mu(n)}=1$} \\
-1,  & \text{then $(-1)^{\mu(n)}=1$} \\
1,  & \text{then $(-1)^{\mu(n)}\in\{1,-1\}$} 
\end{cases}$$

This implies $g(n)+(-1)^{\mu(n)}\ge 0$ and because we know (*from following answers*) $F(a)< 0$ we can conclude $G(a)\ge |F(a)|>0$.

Comment: So you're just asking if the number of square-free numbers less than or equal to $n$ is always greater than $n/2$?

Answer (score 2):

$$|\mu(n)|=\sum_{d^2 |n}\mu(d)$$

$$\sum_{n\le x}|\mu(n)|=\sum_{d^2\le x} \mu(d)\lfloor x/d^2\rfloor\ge 
x\sum_{d^2\le x} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}-x^{1/2}
 $$

$$\sum_{n\le x} (-1)^{\mu(n)}=
x-2\sum_{n\le x}|\mu(n)| \le x(1-2\sum_{d^2\le x} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2})+2x^{1/2}$$

Conclude with $$\sum_{d^2\le x}  \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}\ge \zeta(2)-\frac1{x^{1/2}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer(+1). Is the consequence correct?

Answer (score 2):

If $Q(a)$ is the number of square free integers between $1$ and $a$, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Distribution)
$$\lim\limits_{a\to \infty }{\frac {Q(a)}{a}}={\frac {6}{\pi ^{2}}}$$
or **for large enough** $a$
$$\frac {Q(a)}{a} > \frac {6}{\pi ^{2}} -\varepsilon>\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow\\
Q(a)>\frac{a}{2} \Rightarrow\\
Q(a) > a-Q(a) \Rightarrow$$
$$-Q(a) + (a-Q(a))<0 \tag{1}$$
And [of course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Definition)
$$F(a)=\sum\limits_{x\in\text{Sqare Free}\\x\leq a}(-1)+\sum\limits_{x\notin\text{Sqare Free}\\x\leq a}1=\\
-Q(a)+(a-Q(a))<0$$

Comment: Which is my answer, without the "for large enough"

Comment: @reuns it isn't immediately clear from your answer (at least for me) ... plus I included links to "reputable sources".

Comment: Thank you for your answer(+1). Is the consequence correct?

Comment: @Pruthviraj it should be. With the proof of the limit, there is always a $\varepsilon$ and a starting $a_0$ (depending on the $\varepsilon$) from which $(1)$ is solid true. I didn't include any details of those $\varepsilon$ and $a_0$, I hope you can work them out. The proof for the remaining $\{1,2,...,a_0 -1\}$ set can be delegated to a computer program, which you already know how to do. That will make a complete proof. Alternatively, check the reuns version.

Answer (score 1):

### A basic upper bound

Since $\mu(n)$ is even if and only if $n$ is not square-free, we have

\begin{aligned}
F(a)
&=\sum_{\substack{n\le a\\n\text{ not square-free}}}1-\sum_{\substack{n\le a\\n\text{ square-free}}}1 \\
&=a-2\sum_{\substack{n\le a\\n\text{ square-free}}}1
\end{aligned}

Hence, all we need is to estimate the latter quantity, which can be done using the following fact

$$
\sum_{d^2|n}\mu(d)=
\begin{cases}
1 & d\text{ square-free} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Plugging this in, we have

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\substack{n\le a\\n\text{ square-free}}}1
&=\sum_{n\le a}\sum_{d^2|n}\mu(d)=\sum_{qd^2\le a}\mu(d) \\
&=\sum_{d\le\sqrt a}\mu(d)\sum_{q\le a/d^2}1 \\
&=a\sum_{d\le\sqrt a}{\mu(d)\over d^2}-\sum_{d\le\sqrt a}\mu(d)\{a/d^2\} \\
&\ge{a\over\zeta(2)}-a\sum_{d>\sqrt a}{\mu(d)\over d^2}-\sqrt a \\
&\ge{a\over\zeta(2)}-2\sqrt a-1
\end{aligned}

Plugging this back to $F(a)$, we deduce

$$
F(a)\le a-{2a\over\zeta(2)}+4\sqrt a+2=-Ka+4\sqrt a+2
$$

where $K=12\pi^{-2}-1\approx0.215854$.

### Numerical analysis on the upper bound

To see when this quantity becomes negative, we can analyze the RHS. Since $-K<0$, we see that the upper bound we obtained is a concave-down quadratic curve, so it becomes negative as long as $a$ exceeds the larger root. Applying the quadratic formula, we get

$$
a>\left(2+\sqrt{2K+4}\over K\right)^2
$$

Plugging in the numerical value of $K$ gives that $F(a)<0$ holds for $a\ge362$. Since the OP has shown that $F(a)<0$ holds for $a\le10^4$, we conclude that $F(a)<0$ holds for all positive integer $a$.

### Appendix: proof of an intermediate result

Since $\mu(n)\ge-1$ holds for all $n$, we can obtain a lower bound for the coefficient of $a$ in the above expansion:

$$
\sum_{d\le\sqrt a}{\mu(d)\over d^2}\ge\sum_{d\ge1}{\mu(d)\over d^2}-\sum_{d>\sqrt a}{1\over d^2}
$$

To further estimate the latter sum, we can use the property of monotonic functions to find that

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{d>\sqrt a}{1\over d^2}
&<{1\over(\lfloor\sqrt a\rfloor+1)^2}+\sum_{d=\lfloor\sqrt a\rfloor+2}\int_{d-1}^d{\mathrm dt\over d^2} \\
&<\frac1a+\int_{\sqrt a}^\infty{\mathrm dt\over t^2}=\frac1a+{1\over\sqrt a}
\end{aligned}

Thus, we have

$$
\sum_{d\le\sqrt a}{\mu(d)\over d^2}\ge\sum_{d\ge1}{\mu(d)\over d^2}-\frac1a-{1\over\sqrt a}
$$

and using the knowledge of Euler product the infinite sum evaluates to $1/\zeta(2)$ exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. Currently, I am a beginner in analytic number theory, can you please  more explain the middle of answers portion $$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\substack{n\le a\\n\text{ square-free}}}1
&=... \\
&\ge{a\over\zeta(2)}-2\sqrt a
\end{aligned}$$. Because of the consequences, can we publish this in the Journal of Integer Sequence?

Comment: I have just updated my answer, and I'm not sure what you mean by "we."